# Why does getsockopt return an error?

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I'm hitting a problem with a socket on Windows. Calling getsockopt() always fails. The weird thing is that setsockopt() seems to work (at least it reports success...although the option I am setting does not seem to have the effect that I expect).

My code is below. Running it reports a successful setsockopt call, but getsockopt fails with WSAEFAULT. What am I doing wrong?

```
        struct linger ling;

        ...

        ling.l_onoff = 1;
        ling.l_linger = 10;
        if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &ling, sizeof(ling)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            fprintf(stderr, "******** setsockopt failed\n");
            ret = -1;
            break;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "******** setsockopt success\n");
        }
        if (getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &ling, sizeof(ling)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            fprintf(stderr, "****** failed getting sockopt\n");
            switch(WSAGetLastError()) {
                case WSANOTINITIALISED:
                    fprintf(stderr, "******WSANOTINITIALISED\n");
                    break;
                case WSAENETDOWN:
                    fprintf(stderr, "******WSAENETDOWN\n");
                    break;
                case WSAEFAULT:
                    fprintf(stderr, "******WSAEFAULT\n");
                    break;
                case WSAEINPROGRESS:
                    fprintf(stderr, "******WSAEINPROGRESS\n");
                    break;
                case WSAEINVAL:
                    fprintf(stderr, "******WSAEINVAL\n");
                    break;
                case WSAENOPROTOOPT:
                    fprintf(stderr, "******WSAENOPROTOOPT\n");
                    break;
                case WSAENOTSOCK:
                    fprintf(stderr, "******WSAENOTSOCK\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    fprintf(stderr, "******Unknown error %d\n", ret);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last argument to `getsockopt` is a pointer, not a size_t.

Note from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738544(v=vs.85).aspx) that `getsockopt` is declared as :

```
int getsockopt(
  _In_    SOCKET s,
  _In_    int    level,
  _In_    int    optname,
  _Out_   char   *optval,
  _Inout_ int    *optlen
);
```

You need to initalize an int with the size of `optval` and pass a pointer to that int as last argument. Change your code to:

```
int slen;
..
slen = sizeof ling;
getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &ling, &slen)
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks...I knew it was something simple.

Comment: I would consider this a compiler bug.  You are not supposed to be able to pass any integer (including `sizeof()`) to a pointer without a type-cast. The only exception to that rule is a literal `0`. So, for `getsockopt()` to compile with `sizeof(ling)` as direct input, that implies there is probably a 3rd party overload of `getsockopt()` in scope that takes an integer as input instead of a pointer.

Comment: It's not a compiler bug, the compiler did probably issue a warning for doing so, but it's not considered an error. (The question is tagged C, in C++ it wouldn't compile)